# How can I use geth to browse through the blocks in a local testnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, blocks

I have installed a local Ethereum testnet and I need to browse the blockchain to search for some information without using any smart contract. How can I do that?

Comment: You have [Etherchain Light](https://github.com/gobitfly/etherchain-light), but I think it requires a parity for some things to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use web3 API: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

With web3, you can explore Ethereum, blocks, transactions